# Output all the words in the dictionary that have exactly six consonants (non-vowels) in a row linux?

Tags: linux

This is a simple question for most of you, so hopefully this wont be tough.

I used this command to find all words in the file that are 5 characters in length.

grep -o -w "\w{5}" ~/words | wc -w

any suggestions on how to search for words in the file that do not contain any vowels (a,e,i,o,u) so the result will give me all the words that only contain consonants.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I think you may have misread the question. You're probably supposed to look for words that *include* six consonants in a row, not words that are entirely made up of consonants. (An example of the kind of word I think they're looking for is "la**tchstr**ing".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confused in light of the question title.

These assume that you have one word per line and nothing before or after each word. It's a bit more complicated if you might have multiple words per line.

To find words with no vowels:

```
grep -Eiv '[aeiou]' ~/words
```

To find words with 6 (or more) consonants in a row:

```
grep -Ei '[^aeiou]{6}' ~/words
```

To find words with 6 (and no more) consonants in a row:

```
grep -Ei '[^aeiou]{6}' ~/words | grep -Eiv '[^aeiou]{7}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My teacher wrote this question and i pasted it. Lol I guess i wasnt the only one confused on the exact solution. the first command executed perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is a very simple thing to do, and there'll be plenty of solutions. One of them:

```
grep -v '[aeiou]' ~/words
```

Explanation: `-v` is inverted match, i.e. output all lines that don't the given pattern.